# Passing the variable from parent to child shell via shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

On the parent shell (root) executing the following:

```
SESSION_RECORD=started
```

**Output**:

```
echo $SESSION_RECORD
started
```

However, when I check the status from a shell script, the value is not getting assigned. I am aware it creates a child and executes the script, which is why it doesn't take the variable.

Is there a way I can import that from the parent shell to the child shell?
I don't want to use export as the root variable is dynamic.

### script for ref:

```
#!/bin/bash

session=`echo $SESSION_RECORD`
echo $session
if [ "$session" == "started" ]
then
echo "screen records"
else
echo "screen not started"
fi
```

Basically, my script should check the value of the variable and if it matches it should get into the loop and execute commands further.

The value of the variable `SESSION_RECORD` changes dynamically, so based on the value, I need to run a script.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with *I don't want to use export as the root variable is dynamic*?

Comment: The value of the variable: SESSION_RECORD is written whenever a user logs in.  So its dynamic value and I won't be able to export that. Basically my script should check the value of the variable and if it matches it should get into the loop and execute commands further.

Comment: Still unclear. What make you believe a "written variable" can't be exported (or an exported variable can't be written)?

Comment: the value of the variable SESSION_RECORD changes dynamically, so based on the value, I need to run a script.  Can you try with the script above and give me the snippet if possible?

Comment: A variable value changes when it is set. There doesn't look to be anything specific in your use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63559761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set the value of a variable when you export it. You can do:

```bsh
SESSION_RECORD=started
echo "Now some other stuff"
export SESSION_RECORD && ./myscript
```

and it will export the current value of `SESSION_RECORD` to your script.

Comment: Even `SESSION_RECORD=$SESSION_RECORD ./myscript` would work and would avoid having to export the variable to the _current_ script's environment.

Comment: thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your script a function, then it won't create a subshell while executing, so accessing the variable should work just fine. Maybe that would work for you?

Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
  echo $foo
}
$ source test.sh
$ foo=5
$ foo
5
$ foo=4
$ foo
4
$
```

Comment: I could see that you are using source command there instead of sh command to execute. Source by default doesnt create a subshell to execute, it runs on the parent shell itself.  is there a way to run call the variable and run the script normally like sh script.sh ?

Comment: You could also pass the variables as an argument to the script. Or have either a function or an alias with will do that for you.

Comment: it's actually a dynamic value that triggers only when a user logs in.. Basically my script should check the value of the variable and if it matches it should get into the loop and execute commands further